# Android: get the type of the resource-array obtains from the TypedArray

Tags: android, android-custom-view, typedarray

I have style attribute that can contains integer-array or string-array.
When I tried to obtain the values, I don't know if need to use getResources().getStringArray(resId) or getResources().getIntArray(resId).
How can I know what is the type of the array?

Comment: style attribute or string attribute ?

Comment: style attribue. <attr name="arrayField" format="reference"/> the attribute can contain int or string array.